# How to find the "user_id" from IBM Cloud Watson Assistant?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I need to send the user_id to my webhook for security reasons, for checking if the information to be returned to watson by the webhook belongs to the company this user works for.

In every message sent to watson from my integration, the context variable "user_id" is set to be the "user id" our CRM system already uses.

When we receive the responses from the assistant, the variable is present in the json body, so watson is receiving it.

What I need is that variable to be sent whenever watson perform calls to my webhook. I just don't know how to access it and include as a POST parameter.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: The user_id is not a Watson Assistant user_id but some data you obtained, right? If it is stored in a context variable, you simply reference the variable. This sample code (see the skill file) sends over data from context variables to a webhook: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/tree/cloud-functions

Comment: @data_henrik I already have the system variable "user_id" being set with the values I want, my problem is that I'm not being able to access it inside the nodes, how do I access these variables using the Watson interface?

Comment: And is this a pre- / post- / or node-based webhook? And are you on Classic WA or the new? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-webhook-post has the user_id set. Use "context" as prefix to the tree of variables, see https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-builtin-vars